# C# console app issue - sqlconnection timeouts using multiple sqlcommands

Tags: c#, sql, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

The objective of my console application is to read a table1 from server1.database1 and copy to the same table and database in a different server if that record doesn't already exist in the destination server/database/table.

```
static void Main() {
    try {
        SqlConnection source = new SqlConnection(" blah blah ");
        SqlConnection dest = new SqlConnection(" blah blah ");
        source.Open();
        dest.Open();

        // reads from destination table to make sure data doesn't already exist
        SqlCommand read1 = new SqlCommand(" select string... ", dest);
        object a = read1.ExecuteScalar();
        if (!a.Equals(DBNull.Value)) {
            Console.WriteLine("A record already exists. Press 1 to overwrite:");
            string ans = Console.ReadLine();
            if (ans == "1") {
                // delete row from table if exists
                SqlCommand delete1 = new SqlCommand("DELETE statement...", dest);
                delete1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            else {
                // exit console app
                System.Environment.Exit(1);
            }
        }
        else {
            // reads and copies data from one server to the other
            copyData(selectStr, source, dest, table1, id);
        }
        // Close connections
        connDEV.Close();
        connPROD.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception err) {
        Console.WriteLine(err.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

// Using SQLbulkcopy and SQLDataReader to copy data
static void copyData(string sqlstr, SqlConnection source, SqlConnection dest, string tableName, string fid) {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlstr, source);
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        int count = reader.FieldCount;
        //////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Copies data from from server to another  //
        //////////////////////////////////////////////
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy1 = new SqlBulkCopy(dest)) {
            bulkCopy1.DestinationTableName = tableName;
            try {
                bulkCopy1.WriteToServer(reader);
            }
            catch (Exception err) {
                Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

However, when I execute this code, it seems to time out at line 12, which is the `object a = read1.ExecuteScalar();` line. The error says:

```
system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception (0x80131904: timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> system.componentModel.win32exception (8x80004005): the wait operation timed out...
```

`read1` is only a simple select statement, and when I go to run the statement in SQL management studio, it queries just fine!

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the SQL just incase?

Comment: typo in the connection string?  Also always use `SELECT TOP 1 ...` if you are doing `ExecuteScalar` no reason for the extra rows (and this could be your problem if there is just too much data in the table.)

Comment: @admdrew --- can I ask why you edited this code to put the `{` on the prior line?  In JavaScript this can have a semantic effect but not in C#.  In C# this is typically considered a matter of style and it seems impolite to me to change a user's preference for no purpose.

Comment: The cmd.CommandTimeout property may be too low for this command.  If it's copying an entire table, you may want to give it 10 minutes or something really long (cmd.CommandTimeout = 600).

Comment: Thanks guys. Our DBA messed with some settings in the destination server. i have implemented a longer timeout period anyway as a precaution and also updated the select statement to just select top 1 for the executeScalar().